# ios 6 Search bar works perfect but in ios7 strange issue

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios6, ios7

I am developing an app in that I have used the search bar functionality to search some kind of data. It's working fine in `iOS 6`.

But when I run this app on `iOS 7` my search field goes in status bar field.

Means overlaying it. Why this happening?

Help me out please.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17074365/status-bar-and-navigation-bar-appear-over-my-views-bounds-in-ios-7/18785646#18785646

Comment: Check also this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19121162/uisearchdisplaycontroller-on-ios7

Answer (score 0):

Hope it will help, add it into you `viewDidLoad` method

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7.0f) {
        self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = NO;
        self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In iOS7, your View size is full screen including the area behind Status bar.
You need to modify your UI to support iOS7

You can set the iOS 6/7 delta values in Interface Builder to support iOS7 and iOS6 both.

See this : [iOS 7 status bar back to iOS 6 default style in iPhone app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18294872/ios-7-status-bar-back-to-ios-6-style?lq=1)

Comment: What have you tried? Can you show us please? I have done the same thing and it worked.

Comment: i have used storyboard in that i have drop search bar in storyboard... when i clicked on search bar it goes to top i dot want this...

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple solution i have tried.

```
  if ([[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion floatValue] >= 7.0f)
    {

        self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
        self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden=YES;

    }
```